# Google Analytics event tracking with user meta data

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics event tracking to track various events. for one f my use case i.e fr sign up page I want to track the details of the failed sign up user using Event tracking. Is this possible using Event tracking.

The syntax for event tracking is,

```
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);
```

I tried to pass the user data as below,

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play',{ 'email' : 'testuser@gmail.com' })
```

but this did not worked.

Comment: Collecting personal info (email) with GA is frowned upon

Answer (score 0):

GA and other Google services does not allow PII so i suggest you take a look at [this](http://dmitriilin.com/encrypt-personally-identifiable-information-using-google-tag-manager/). Maybe you can adapt it to work on your site.

Finally i think you can not send the email as a filed object maybe you should be using a custom dimension.